# Why does object-fit not affect images?

Tags: html, css, image

I have two images inside a div. I want the two images to fill the entirety of the div which should be the entire height and width of the webpage. The only problem is, when I use the object-fit attribute, the images don't contain within my container at all. It's almost as if I didn't include the attribute at all. Any way I could get some help with this? Thanks.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
 margin: 0; 
}

.container {
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
 max-height: 100vh;
}

.image1 {
 object-fit: contain;
 z-index: 1;
 
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.image2 {
 object-fit: contain;
 z-index: 2;
 
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Sylvanas</title>
 <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
  <img class="image1" src="Image_Template_1.png">
  <img class="image2" src="Image_Template_2.png">
  
  
 </div>


 <script src="script.js">
 </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define `width` and `height` for images, `object-fit` property tries to scale image within its tag size and without proper sizing this property does not work

see: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Answer (score 0):

Check this type `CSS` Script Once,
And You define the `height` and `width` for image to fit the images in web page

```
.image1 {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("Image_Template_1.jpg");

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.image2 {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("Image_Template_2.jpg");

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

and you define the `div` class inside the `body` tag like this

```
<body>
<div class="image1"></div>
<div class="image2"></div>
<body>
```